# How to refresh other html page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a question. I have two different html files. One is index html, and other is modal pop up. In that pop up I have submit input. Is there a way to trigger onclick function on that input and refresh index html. because in my case it only refreshes modal.html.

My code snippet:

```
<input type="submit" value="Kurti nauja produkta" name = "submitprod" onClick="window.location.reload();">
```

Comment: Can you show how you loaded `modal.html` inside of `index.html`?

Comment: I used php. include 'details-modal.php';

Comment: <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#details-<?=$product['details'];?>">More</button>

Comment: Can you show `modal.html`? The answer is different depending on what markup you put in there, i.e. if you change the context of the current `window`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refresh the parent of the iframe this way:

```
parent.location.reload();
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of your current function call on onClick, try this:

```
onclick="location.replace('index.html')"
```

Let's be clear though; you've mentioned that this is a submit button and you want to submit something as such. Your current code snippet isn't submitting anything, just refreshing the page (or in this fix, replacing it). Just to be clear, that's all that's doing. If you're looking for help submitting information and refreshing, that is a seperate question.

Answer (score 1):

Use `window.location.reload(true);`
Find details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload)